# How many isochronous USB2.0 devices can a USB3.0 Hub enumerate?

Tags: usb

I am working on a hardware-embedded software project involving USB protocol. My plan is to use a USB3.0 Hub that clusters many USB2.0 isochronous devices, each requiring around 33 Mbps BW.

Now, I know that USB3 is able to enumerate up to 127 devices [[1](https://www.usb3.com/whitepapers/USB%203%200%20(11132008)-final.pdf)], what I'd like to know is whether this is true if I connect USB2 devices to the USB3 Hub. Can I, in theory, use the hub with 97 USB2 devices?

Also, could I utilize the entire BW (yes, only around 70% is feasible) of a USB3 port this way? The above figures add up to `5 Gbps*70% = 3.2 Gbps = 97*33Mbps`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is some confusion with your understanding.
USB 3.0 hub contains 2 logical hub partitions.

1 - USB 3.0 hub
2 - USB 2.0 hub

USB 2.0 devices communicate through the USB 2.0 hub data path which has nothing to do with USB 3.0 data path. So the assumption of the bandwidth is incorrect as they are for USB 3.0 devices connected via USB 3.0 data path.

Also USB 2.0 devices will get connected via USB 2.0 lines and NOT USB 3.0 lines.

Another misconception in your question.

The speed which you mentioned i.e. 5 Gbps, that is USB 3.0 link speed.
What that means is that 2 devices over USB 3.0 link can send or receive data at 5 Gbps. Since every hub downstream port is physically a separate link, the link speed will be same for all i.e. 5 Gbps. So its speed between 2 link partners and not end to end speed.

Now when you say End to End data transfer rate, that will depend on your host controller driver architecture, your OS performance, your Hub, etc.

For Isochronous endpoints, the hub will start data transfer on service intervals for each endpoints on each port as per USB spec but you cannot be sure that End to End data transfer rate will be equally divided.

PS - You will get a lot less end to end bandwidth by the way as the link speed for USB 2.0 is 480 Mbps. :)

Comment: Hi Shaibal, thanks for the reply! I have to bear in mind that the iso transfer rates are unequally divided. It makes sense. I'll probably use them as interrupt devices, since it's important that all devices get the same BW. Nevertheless, my problem explanation might have been unclear. I know that the 97 devices would be connected as USB2, but that's fine because I don't need more speed for them individually. As long as the hub can scan all devices for data fast enough and use USB3 as upstream, it's fine for my design. Any thoughts, @[Shaibal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1263525/shaibal) ?

Comment: @davidanderle "use USB3 as upstream" wrong statement. USB 2.0 hub will be connected to USB 2.0 ports upstream. So there is no USB 3.0 in the whole data path. Also like I said, End-to-End bandwidth is not predictable at all. As far as I know, for Isochronous endpoints, the hubs do not include any big delays. Hub will use the same service interval which was used by root port to send the packet. As for the endpoint type, I guess there is still some understanding required. The use case of interrupt and isoch endpoints are completely different.

Comment: Ah, I understand... It seems I do have to implement the connected devices as USB3.0 to get the required speed. Thanks, I'll figure something out!